# Android: Why does calling viewToFront() on a SeekBar not bring it to the top of the UI?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a hidden `SeekBar` (originally with `visibility = "gone"`) visible and be displayed on top of a black background LinearLayout that covers the entire screen. However, when I run my code, I just see the fullscreen `LinearLayout` and I do not see a `SeekBar` that is on top of that `LinearLayout`:

[image]

Below is my code:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.changingimageviewwidth;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Make the image preview box visible
        SeekBar seekbar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        seekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        seekbar.bringToFront();

        // Place the image preview box at a specified location
        seekbar.setX(150);
        seekbar.setY(150);

        seekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        seekbar.bringToFront();

        // Place the image preview box at a specified location
        seekbar.setX(150);
        seekbar.setY(150);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question but it may solve the problem. You can use a `ConstraintLayout` to position the `SeekBar`. It is a flat hierarchy so you can stack views on top of each other and then you can use `visibility` to hide/show it, instead of moving it into place it is always there.